# Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'boolean[]'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I would like to create a switch between tabs based on a boolean array. However, I do not know how to replace the switchTabs function to stop this error from being displayed.
The interface is built like this:

```
interface IData {
    setData: boolean[];
}
```

My constructor looks like this:

```
  constructor(props: IData) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            setData: [true, false, false]
        }
    }
```

However, the method in which the error (*Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'boolean[]'*) occurs looks like this:

```
 private switchTabs() {
        this.setState({ setData: !this.state.setData});
    }
```

Comment: a single boolean is not an array of booleans.

Comment: What do you expect `!this.state.setData` to do?

Comment: !this.state.setData returns boolean

Comment: `{ setData: this.state.setData.map(x => !x) }`?

Comment: an array of boolean is not a single boolean, either. So trying to invert an array, does not work.

Comment: If you're trying to flip one of the booleans in that array, you'll need to know which one.

Comment: I want the values ​​to change to the opposite

Comment: @0316 I hope you've had your question answered. it really helps to mark an answer as accepted, for those who have provided an answer for you :)

Answer (score 0):

per @evolutionxbox comment:

```js
private switchTabs() {
        this.setState({ setData: this.state.setData.map( x=>!x});
    }
```

using .map will apply a function against each element in an array. This is nice, tidy notation.  This is inverting each boolean value in the array. I'm not exactly sure what will happen if your array contains a non-boolean element though.

Answer (score 0):

You're denying the array of booleans `!this.state.setData` which evaluates to false. Thus throwing that error.

Instead you should create a copy of the array and modify the desired index

```js
private switchTabs(tabIndex) {
        const newData = [...this.state.setData]; //copying the array
        newData[tabIndex] = !newData[tabIndex];
        this.setState({ setData: newData});
    }
```